# Ruby / Rails: Assigning values to an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, variable-assignment, instance-variables

What is the easiest way to assign attribute values to the (model) instance variable, when these attribute values are located in a big hash (session[:some_big_hash]) that contains the usual model attribute values but also other key-value pairs (that don't belong to the model)?

The situation looks like this:

```
# 1. Get the user from the db:
@user = User.where(id: 1).first

# 2. Add some additional data from a hash inside the session
@user = @user.somehow_extract_the_values_for_the_model_from(session[:some_big_hash])
```

Comment: @apneadiving can you join here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27184/ruby-conceptual

Comment: @apneadiving: Step 2. is supposed to find all values in session[:some_big_hash] that the model instance can have assigned, and then assign exactly those values (potentially overwriting any existing attribute values), but ignore the rest of session[:some_big_hash] because trying to do something like user = User.new(session[:some_big_hash]) would obviously fail. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the values to the session at first place, you should use

```
session[:user_specific_attributes] = {...}
```

instead of adding them directly to the "root" of the session hash.

So later, you could do:

```
@user.foo(session[:user_specific_attributes])
```

Comment: What would ".foo" be here exactly? It couldn't be .new since it would discard the values retrieved from the db...

Comment: This is another question though. It could be `update_attributes`.